# Undefined Index while uploading file

Tags: php

This is my error:

> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Template1\users\index.php on line 21 Notice:
>   Undefined index: file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Template1\users\index.php on line 23  please
>   uploaded

How to get rid of it?

Html Code:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Php Code:

```
<?php

    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['file']['temp_name'];

    if (isset($name)) {

        if (!empty($name)) {
            $location = '../uploads/';
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)) {
            echo 'uploaded';
        }

    } else {
        echo 'please uploaded';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change your PHP script as below and try

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];  
        $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
        if(isset($name) and !empty($name)){
            $location = '../uploads/';      
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                echo 'File uploaded successfully';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 35):

Make sure you have set form attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

This attribute help you to get files from user.

```
<form action="PATH" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

Answer (score 7):

this happens due to the size of the file :

`max_execution_time` = 300
`max_input_time` = 240
`post_max_size` = 128M
`upload_max_filesize` = 128M

in your php.ini file you should change above codes according to your requirement...

Comment: I believe this is most of the case.

Answer (score 1):

Spelling mistake:

```
<?php
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // tmp_name

    if(isset($name)){
        if(!empty($name)){

            $location = '../uploads/';
        }
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'uploaded';
        }
    }  else {
        echo 'please uploaded';
    }
?>
```

Comment: **Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Template1\users\index.php on line 21**
still getting this error.

**Line 21 **
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

Comment: If the file has not been uploaded then $_FILES['file'] will not exist. So check isset($_FILES['file']) before you use it, or supress the warnings with @

Answer (score 1):

Do a check around your PHP code block checking if either the submit button has been pressed or if `isset($_FILES['file'])`. This should remove your errors. They pop up because the $_FILES['file'] isn't populated before the submit button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the problem is forgetting to add this line as a form tag attribute.

`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

The enctype attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.

Note: The enctype attribute can be used only if method="post".

Answer (score 0):

```
$upload_dir="../uploads";
$target_file="";
$tmp_file="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

        $tmp_file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $target_file=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $upload_dir."/".$target_file))
        {   
        echo "File uploaded <br />";

        }
        else {
              echo "Something went Wrong !!<br/>";
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting **Notice: Undefined index: zip_file in** error message most of the time, While uploading any file to server using php, Then here is the solution for this. only you need to mention **enctype** type in form tag.

```
<form method="post" action="" name="login" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if *file_uploads* is enabled on your php.ini

```
file_uploads = On
```

Comment: @thanksd what you wrote is incorrect. I have a good motivation because if the index is undefined on upload may depend of $ _FILES is empty, and therefore, if $_FILES is empty might depend that file_uploads is disabled on php.ini

Answer (score -3):

the solid solution to this problem is to use

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-button'])){
 $option="";
  $option=$_POST["anbieterin_geburtstag_month"];

  echo $option;
  }
```

always use isset function