# $_FILES not working in php

Tags: php, html

I want to upload image but there is an error like this

> Notice: Undefined index: img in /xxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/add-currency.php on line 12

and code is here

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $logo = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
    $logo_tmp = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
    $file_path = "images/".$logo;
    move_uploaded_file($logo_tmp, $file_path);  

}
```

and html code id here

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>Logo</label><br>
            <input type="file" name="img" />
        </div>                      
    </div>
    <br>            
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button name="submit" class="btn m-btn--pill m-btn--air btn-primary" type="submit" style="float:right;">Submit</button>
        </div>                      
    </div>
</form>
```

its work another demo is complete but not in this file

Comment: Well, your code allows me to upload any trojans I want to :)

Comment: Huh? You are happy about that?

Comment: @bub maybe it's a trojan upload plateform, you never know ;) :p

Comment: @teeyo you definitley made my day.... :) Can't stop laughing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined Index while uploading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027992/undefined-index-while-uploading-file)

Comment: Start by checking the duplicate marked by @Panther

Comment: Do you get the error as soon as you access the page, or is it when you upload a file?

Comment: Check var_dump($_FILES['img']) to see what's in there. As this error says, your file input is not submitted to this script.

Comment: var_dump($_FILES['img']).......Result is NULL

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right and it is working fine on my side. Whatever you are getting is not an error, it is a notice which don't affect functionality.

```
Notice: Undefined index: img in /xxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/add-currency.php on line 12
```

It might be because you used **img** before defining it. Even there is no error, your code will work fine it is just a notice.

Comment: He just asked about the notice he is getting not about what he wants to upload. That is his decision and he have code for that.

Comment: there is $_POST['img'] is complete work but not $_FILES['img']['name'] worked

Comment: $_FILES["img"]["name"]; is working on my side. It is printing image name which I uploaded.

Comment: Can you paste complete code so that I will get idea about error.