# issue related to upload a file through PHP script

Tags: php

Following kind of errors I am getting while try to upload a file on server using PHP script:

Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP-Practice-file1\upload.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP-Practice-file1\upload.php on line 8

Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP-Practice-file1\upload.php on line 8
File is not an image.
Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP-Practice-file1\upload.php on line 23
Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

This is my html code:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h2>Upload a file</h2>
            <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Select image to upload:
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD IMAGE">
            </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my upload.php file:

```html
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you echo out `$imageFileType` under `$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));` and show us what the echo is.

Comment: Also, have a look at this. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027992/undefined-index-while-uploading-file]