# PHP Uploading image form doesn't work on Win 10

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload image with php into database, but it seems to have a problem with the Windows version which I use...I am using the same code on my laptop(Win 10) as my PC(Win 8), but on my laptop the code doesn't work. The form on my PC works perfectly. I am using same files, same databases, same DB tables, same php versions, same php.ini settings...everything is the same except Windows versions. On my laptop I'm getting error Undefined index: file in.... How can I fix that ?

```
<?php
  $submit = $_POST["submit"];
  if(!isset($submit))
  {
      $URL="index.php";
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';</script>";
      echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';
  }
  else
  {
      require 'inc/dbconn.php';
      $directory = "uploadings/";
      $file = $directory . basename($_FILES["picture"]["name"]);
      $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
      $check = getimagesize($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"]);
      $name = $_POST["product"];
      $price = $_POST["price"];
      if ($check == false) {
          echo "File is not an image";

      }
      elseif (empty($name)) {
          echo "Empty productname";
      }
      elseif (empty($price)) {
          echo "Empty price";
      }
      else {
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbupload(picture, product, price) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
          $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $file, $name, $price);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->close();
          $conn->close();
          $upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], $file);
          $URL="view.php";
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';</script>";
          echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';
      }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Have you searched for your error, a quick search return this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027992/undefined-index-while-uploading-file

Comment: Can you give me the exact error with line code, etc.?

Comment: I searched solution for this error and I tryed everyting but without results...I don't get error now but It still don't save picture url in database and don't upload image in the folder. *Michael Muryn

Comment: But you said "On my laptop I'm getting error Undefined index: file in.... How can I fix that ?" -- so I was expecting that error.  I will suggest you try to breakdown the problem step by step.  Try to just upload an image on the machine that it causes problem, does it works?  If not, we need to debug that.  If yes, you add one step.  Could it simply be directory permissions (read/write/etc.)?  If it is permission, try to change permissions or change the place you save your upload.  Etc.