# Why " $_FILES " not working .Throwing error (Undefined array key "image" )

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload the name of the selected file to the database. For this I made a HTML page . The code of HTML page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Photo Input</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="input-photo.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        <h3>Insert a photo</h3>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="1"  >
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload image">
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The action of this form in HTML is in input-photo.php file . The code of this php file is

```
<?php
    $server = "localhost";
    $username ="root";
    $password = "";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,"form");
    if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {
        $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        echo $name;
    }
?>
```

But when i run this segment of code it shows two warnings:-
Warning: Undefined array key "image"
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

The warning is shown for the .php file where $_FILES is used. It says Undefined array key "image"
I dont know how to resolve this.

Comment: When do you see this error? After submitting the form? When opening the page directly?

Comment: When i click the upload image then the error is shown.

Comment: Do any of the answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027992/undefined-index-while-uploading-file

Comment: It looks like it should work.  You have selected a file?  Try `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: Make sure to check your `file_uploads=On` in php.ini file

Comment: Debugging is a skill =) If you got "undefined .." then var_dump the heck out of the variable you tried to access.