# PHP form using Post. Error: Undefined array key

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

HTML:

```
    <form  action="submit.php" method="POST" >
 <div class="file-input">
              
              <input type="file" class="attestat" id="attestat" name="attestat" accept="application/pdf, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, image/*" multiple="multiple">
              <span class="file-name">Выберите файл</span>
            </div>
</form>
```

and PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Youshit21";
$dbname = "medacc";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



  $filetmpname = $_FILES["attestat"]["tmp_name"];

  $id = uniqid('user_');

  $sql = "INSERT INTO medacc.spaco(id,filo) VALUES ('$id', '$filetmpname')";
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "File uploaded successfully.";
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }





$conn->close();

?>
```

and its always showing this error:
Warning: Undefined array key "attestat" in D:\localhost\acceptance form\submit.php on line 14

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in D:\localhost\acceptance form\submit.php on line 14

the code inserts file to mysql table , but its simply does not see the file input
and doesnt change no matter what i do`your text`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php ... missing enctype

Comment: can you tell in more detail?

Comment: You did not add multipart/form-data in the form tag.

Comment: Also, be warned that your `INSERT`  query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: If you want to handle file uploads, `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is a **must**!

Comment: You would be much better off having `id` being an auto-incrementing field.

Comment: I would also recommend that you read [Uploading multiple files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) in the manual since you have set the `multiple`-attribute on the file-input.

Answer (score 0):

you are not submitting the form i guess .. moreover since you are accepting multiple files it would require something like this

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="file-input">
    <input type="file" class="attestat" id="attestat" name="attestat[]" accept="application/pdf, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, image/*" multiple="multiple">
    <span class="file-name">Выберите файл</span>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

please add this attribute in form tag
enctype="multipart/form-data" to solve your issue.
like this:

```
 <form  action="submit.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

for more details you can follow [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

Comment: This has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027992/undefined-index-while-uploading-file Please do not add duplicate answers.